# scanf() and floating point numbers in Turbo C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion, turbo-c

I created a structure as:

```
typedef struct {
  float real, img;
} cmplx;
```

And I created a function as

```
void input(cmplx *a) {
  scanf("%f + %f i", &a->real, &a->img); 
}
```

and called the function from main as:

```
cmplx a;
input(&a);
```

The execution stops when the `scanf` is reached.  If floats are replaced by ints, the problem is solved. What is this behaviour? Is there a way I can use floats for my problem?

The program was compiled in [Turbo C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B), in [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP).

Comment: What input are you giving to the program?

Comment: (a) Check the value returned by `scanf()`; it tells you how many of the conversions worked.  (b) Does your C runtime library support floating point operations automatically, or do you have to tell the compiler to link with the floating-point enabled library?  Converted into runnable code on Mac OS X, it works fine given valid input.

Comment: is there any code i can write to tell compiler to link floating point library? Or we shoud compilers params

Comment: Turbo C is a very old compiler, I believe.  You'll need to read the manual.  Your code is good for a modern system, so explaining why it doesn't work will delve into what is different about your compiler compared to modern ones.

Comment: *"The execution stops"* -- and then what happens? Do you mean that the program terminates? Is there an error message, and if so, what is it?

Comment: @KeithThompson  I mean the program terminates. And it was a compiler problem actually, the linking was the error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to answer without knowing the error message that your program's execution stops with, but from your comment "is there any code i can write to tell compiler to link floating point library", 
  I suspect it may be [this issue](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part2/section-5.html):

> "Floating point formats not linked" is a Borland run-time error (Borland
>    C or C++, Turbo C or C++). Borland's compilers try to be smart and not
>    link in the floating- point (f-p) library unless you need it. Alas, they
>    all get the decision wrong. One common case is where you don't call any
>    f-p functions, but you have %f or other f-p formats in scanf() or
>    printf() calls. The cure is to call an f-p function, or at least force
>    one to be present in the link.
>
> To do that, define this function somewhere in a source file but don't
>    call it:
>
> ```
> static void forcefloat(float *p)
> { 
>     float f = *p;
>     forcefloat(&f);
> }
> ```
>
> It doesn't have to be in the module with the main program, as long as
>    it's in a module that will be included in the link.
>
> If you have Borland C++ 3.0, the README file documents a slightly less
>    ugly work-around. Insert these statements in your program:
>
> ```
> extern unsigned _floatconvert;
> #pragma extref _floatconvert
> ```

Using this workaround, or a more modern compiler, will probably fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with using years old C compiler  like TurboC, as it works fine for me (I am Using DevC++)
check [this discussion](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/329012/when-scaning-float-value-in-structure-which-produce-error#) for similar issue

Comment: compulsion of what? using legacy TurboC Compiler

Comment: I suggest - Upgrade to modern compilers

Comment: I suspect he or she meant "compulsory"